# Django add custom form errors to form.errors

Tags: django, django-forms, django-validation

I want to write a form for registering a user. I want to implement a *password match* where the user has to type in his password twice. This is my current form:

```
from django import forms
from passwords.fields import PasswordField

class AccountForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=255)
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=40)
    password = PasswordField(label="Password")
    password_confirm = PasswordField(label="Password")
```

In my view I want to check for validations, and if something is not valid I want to print the specific error in my template. This is the current state of my views:

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AccountForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            password_confirm = form.cleaned_data['password_confirm']

            if password != password_confirm:
                print("Password don't match")

            #Account.objects.create_user(email, password, username = username)

        else:
            print(form.errors)
            form = Account()
    return render(request, 'authentication/auth.html', {'signup': form})
```

Now my aim is to deliver the form errors to the template. I check for example the match of the `password` with the `password_confirm` variable. If they don't match I want that to be visible in the template. Do you guys know how I can add my custom form errors / validations to my form and display these errors in my template?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For this, you need to use the `clean` method.

```
class AccountForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=255)
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=40)
    password = PasswordField(label="Password")
    password_confirm = PasswordField(label="Password")

    def clean(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data
        if cd.get('password') != cd.get('password_confirm'):
            self.add_error('password_confirm', "passwords do not match !")
        return cd
```

Now, when `form.is_valid()` is called from your view, the form's `clean` method is called implicitly and this validation is executed.

Read on this: [`clean values that depend on each other`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) for more info.

> Note that any errors raised by your Form.clean() override will not be
>   associated with any field in particular. They go into a special
>   “field” (called **all**), which you can access via the
>   non_field_errors() method if you need to. If you want to attach errors
>   to a specific field in the form, you need to call `add_error()`.

Also, note that `.add_error` was introduced in django 1.7.

If you are using django 1.6 or below, you would do:

```
if cd.get('password') != cd.get('password_confirm'):
    self._errors["password_confirm"] = self.error_class(["Passwords do not match"])
    del cleaned_data["password_confirm"]
```

Comment: Woooow this is really awesome! I didn't know that the clean method can do that :D Thank you very much!

Comment: It looks like a lot of this code could be reduced by using `ModelForms` - would encourage you to readup on that.

Comment: If you need to use more complex logic than a simple validator, this is very useful when combined with [the ability to capture the output of the `ValidationError`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4690655/5544691).  Something like `except ValidationError as ve: self.add_error("field", ve)` (but formatted with proper line breaks)

Answer (score 4):

```
class AccountForm(forms.Form):
    ....your stuff

    def clean_password(self):
        if self.data['password'] != self.data['password_confirm']:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords are not the same')
        return self.data['password']
```