# User Defined and built in Arguments in exceptions

Tags: python, exception

The following code when executed doesn't result in argument( i.e : Divide by Zero is not permitted ) being printed. It only gives built in error message from-
ZeroDivisionError. So, whats the use of user defined arguments when built in error messages are available.

```
print "Enter the dividend"
dividend=input()
print "Enter the divisor"
divisor=input()

try:
    result=dividend/divisor
except "ZeroDivisonError",argument:
    print "Divide by Zero is not permitted \n ",argument # Argument not getting printed
else:   
    print "Result=%f" %(result)
```

Comment: Please, format your code appropriately

Comment: That's not how exceptions and exception handling work.

Comment: `except "ZeroDivisonError",argument` is invalid Python.

Comment: @Rogalski: It's valid, just absolutely not what you want to do.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690600/python-exception-message-capturing?

Comment: Maybe `except <anything> as argument`?

Comment: try googling or read the documentation, especially this chapter https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spelling of "ZeroDivisonError" is incorrect and moreover it shouldnt be in "".
Correct line:

```
    except ZeroDivisionError,argument:
    print "Divide by Zero is not permitted \n ",argument
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your Exception generic works:

```
dividend=int(input("Enter the dividend: "))
divisor=int(input("Enter the divisor: "))

try:
    result=dividend/divisor
except Exception,argument:
    print "Divide by Zero is not permitted \n ",str(argument) # Argument not getting printed
else:   
    print "Result=%f" %(result)
```

And if your want to define your own exception, follow this way:

```
# Define a class inherit from an exception type
class CustomError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        # Set some exception infomation
        self.msg = arg

try:
    # Raise an exception with argument
    raise CustomError('This is a CustomError')
except CustomError, arg:
    # Catch the custom exception
    print 'Error: ', arg.msg
```

You can find this template here: [Proper way to define python exceptions](http://code.runnable.com/Uqh0fAqimz52AAI6/custom-exception-in-python)

Comment: It works now. The spelling of division in ZeroDivisonError is wrong!. But after fixing it, argument is getting printed now.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with ZeroDivisionError, but what he wrote in line is a string. This should be an object from the Exception class, not a string.

Comment: @LingboTang print accepts objects also and print them successfully

Comment: @frist Again, it isn't a problem with print(). However, the syntax he used to throw the exception is not correct.

Comment: @Butters If you want to accept this answer, you can click the check sign.

Comment: @LingboTang you mean catch (or except)? He doesn't throw (raise) exception it's been raised by division operation :-)

Comment: @frist Here, as what he mentioned in his own answer: `except "ZeroDivisonError",argument:`, which is a syntax of `except <string>,arg` should be changed to the pattern: `except <Exception>, arg`