# How to check what message inside of an exception

Tags: python, discord.py

I have this error.

```
discord.errors.ClientException: Already playing audio.
```

This is what I have done to catch the error

```py
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_error(self, err):
        if isinstance(err, commands.ClientException()):
            print("Client Exception")
```

I would also like to check if "Already playing audio" is in this 'ClientException: Already playing audio'. But how do I get the message out of the Exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will print the exception message if there is any exception.

```
try:
    ans = 'hi' + 5
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

```
can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

You can do something like this in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do err.message to print the message from exception. You can also refer to this link [python exception message capturing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690600/python-exception-message-capturing)