# Selenium + Python: Unable to catch a TimeoutException with Try & WebDriverWait

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, timeoutexception

> Python version: 3.10; Selenium Webdriver: Firefox; IDE: PyCharm 2021.3.2 (CE); OS: Fedora 35 VM

I am writing a python selenium script to scrape data from a website.
I would like to navigate through a website, find an element & print it.  I am able to do this when the element is present.
My problem is that sometimes the element is not present & I get an exception.
If the element is not present when I use this code:

```
 RemainDeductible = (WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "b8-b36-Input_RemainAmtYr1"))).get_attribute("value"))
```

the script produces the following exception:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  
 File "...PythonSeleniumScript.py", line 152, in <module>
    RemainDue = (WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "b8-b36-Input_RemainAmtYr1"))).get_attribute("value"))

 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 89, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)

 selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:183:5
NoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:395:5
element.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.js:300:16
```

If the Timeout Exception occurs I would like to catch the exception & set the "Remain Due" variable to the string "BLANK".
I still get the following Timeout Exception if I use Try in my code as follows:

```
try:
    RemainDue = (WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "b8-b36-Input_RemainAmtYr1"))).get_attribute("value"))
except TimeoutException:
    RemainDue = "BLANK"
```

I still get the Timeout Exception. I thought my code would catch the exception. Why is it not catching it???

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  
 File "...PythonSeleniumScript.py", line 155, in <module>
    RemainDue = (WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "b8-b36-Input_RemainAmtYr1"))).get_attribute("value"))

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 89, in until

    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)

 selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:183:5
NoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:395:5
element.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.js:300:16
```

The relevant HTML for the element I am trying to locate is:

```
<input id="b8-b36-Input_RemainAmtYr1"
class="form-control OSFillParent" data-
input="" disabled="" type="text"
style="margin-top: 5px;" value="$10.50">
event
```

Of course the code does work *when the element is present*. My issue is that the code crashes with the Timeout Exception when the element is ***not*** present.
When the Timeout Exception occurs how do I catch the Timeout Exception & set the "Remain Due" variable to the string "BLANK"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest several things here:

1. instead of

```py
except TimeoutException:
```

Try using

```py
except:
```

I understand that it's preferable to catch a specific exception type rather any exception, but I will still advice doing that here.
2) I would suggest using `visibility_of_element_located` instead of `presence_of_element_located` since `presence_of_element_located` will wait for presence of such element on the page only while it may still not be completely rendered. While `visibility_of_element_located` will wait for much more mature element state, when it is visible.
So instead of

```py
try:
    RemainDue = (WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "b8-b36-Input_RemainAmtYr1"))).get_attribute("value"))
except TimeoutException:
    RemainDue = "BLANK"
```

I would suggest you using

```py
try:
    RemainDue = (WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "b8-b36-Input_RemainAmtYr1"))).get_attribute("value"))
except:
    RemainDue = "BLANK"
```

Also make sure the `id` value of `b8-b36-Input_RemainAmtYr1` is fixed, not changing.

Comment: The id value of b8-b36-Input_RemainAmtYr1 is fixed as long as the element is present. When the element is not present of course there is no id either.

Comment: Are you sure you keep a correct indentation there? If yes (and you are 100% sure) - can you share more your code? Because this code itself should work....

Comment: So, what was the issue?

Comment: Changing from ``except TimeoutException:`` to ``except :`` did work. Much appreciated but why was this necessary? What other exception could it have been generating? How do I print the exceptions without having it stop the code?

Comment: The first time I changed to ``except:`` it did not work because I forgot to comment out the original code ``RemainDeductible = (WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "b8-b36-Input_RemainAmtYr1"))).get_attribute("value"))``. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690600/python-exception-message-capturing you can see how to print the exception message. there are more questions / tutorials about that

Comment: In order to see why the `except TimeoutException:` did not work I would need to debug your code, but you didn't give all the details and all your code here. But you can print the actual error using the `except Exception as e: # work on python 3.x
    logger.error('Failed to upload to ftp: '+ str(e))` or similar as described there