# How do i return error in exception in python?

Tags: python, exception, return

I want to return the error in my code that I wrote in python. I can't do this. How can I do it?

```py
def proc():
    try:
        a=2/0
    except Exception as e:
        print("Except")
        raise f"{e}"
    else:
        return "Success"

result=proc()
print("result : ",result)
```

I tried using direct raise but it didn't work? How can I do?

Comment: If you want the error to be reported just don't catch it.
And you'll get the `ZeroDivisionError` raised inside `proc()`.

Comment: Don't you just want to return the error? Instead of raising it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python exception message capturing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690600/python-exception-message-capturing)

Comment: How do you know it didn't work? See how to create a [mcve] and [edit] the question. You used to be able to raise a string literal as an exception in Python 2, but this has been deprecated for a long time, [since 2.5](https://peps.python.org/pep-0352/), and removed in 3.0.

Comment: What **exactly** do you want to return? Did you notice the TypeError when you tried running this code? Have you looked at the documentation for raise. If not, here it is for your convenience: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#raise

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to return the error message with the class name, you could probably do this:

```py
def proc():
    try:
        a=2/0
    except Exception as e:
        print("Except")
        return repr(e) # Repr is a great solution
    else:
        return "Success"

result=proc()
print("result : ",result)
```

Result:

```
Except
result :  ZeroDivisionError(division by zero)
```